# Static files not loading using nginx and docker

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm having approximately the same error as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73062847/unable-to-serve-django-static-files-via-nginx-and-docker), as concerning Django, all my pages are loaded correctly but not my static files. I guess it has something to do with an error in my configuration files, however even though I've been searching for quite some time, I couldn't find anything to solve my problem.

Here is my Django Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.10.5-alpine

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/First-google-logo.gif -O media/media.gif

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./src /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream django {
    server django_gunicorn:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /media/;
    }
}
```

**nginx Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    env_file:
      - env
    build:
      context: .
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn

volumes:
  static:
  media:
```

And I get errors like that :

```
testapp-django_gunicorn-1  |
testapp-django_gunicorn-1  | 9771 static files copied to '/app/static'.
testapp-django_gunicorn-1  | [2022-07-21 12:27:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
testapp-django_gunicorn-1  | [2022-07-21 12:27:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (9)
testapp-django_gunicorn-1  | [2022-07-21 12:27:36 +0000] [9] [INFO] Using worker: sync
testapp-django_gunicorn-1  | [2022-07-21 12:27:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
testapp-nginx-1            | 172.20.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2022:12:30:45 +0000] "GET /scripts/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17460 "http://127.0.0.1/scripts/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
testapp-nginx-1            | 172.20.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2022:12:30:45 +0000] "GET /static/scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://127.0.0.1/scripts/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
testapp-nginx-1            | 2022/07/21 12:30:45 [error] 30#30: *1 open() "/static/scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.20.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /static/scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/scripts/"
```

EDIT : **entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic

gunicorn main.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: what's in `entrypoint.sh`?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: Doesn't nginx need a `root /app;` to know where to look for `/static`?

Comment: wait...  maybe the issue is you're serving out of `/static` but the `collectstatic` is putting everything in `/app/static` which isn't actually in your shared volume.  Try getting a shell in the nginx container and see if the contents are actually there.

Comment: Where would I need to put this ? I tried doing `- static:root /app/static` in my nginx volumes but that didn't work, so either I didn't understand well or it doesn't work. (I also tried  `- static:/app/static` but didn't work neither)

Comment: It seems I have no container as I did `docker ps` and got no result...I'm still too new to Docker I think I'll try to learn a bit more about it then come back, else I'll just make you lose your time.

Comment: I was referring to the nginx config (not docker-compose), but I think your `alias` is fine.  Your nginx container is looking for static in `/static/` but the logs show you're collecting static in `/app/static/` in the gunicorn container.  In docker-compose, did you try `- static:/app/static` on the gunicorn side and `- static:/static` on the nginx side?

Comment: That worked, that was the only thing I didn't try, I feel so dumb, but thanks anyway :) You can post it as an answer, I'll accept it !

Comment: `docker ps` only shows running containers.  If you run `docker-compose up` in one terminal, you can do `docker ps` in another and then do `docker exec -it [container_hash] bash` to get shell access.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the info, I knew there was something I didn't understand

Comment: You're doing well!  Keep at it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your nginx container is looking for static in `/static/` but the logs show you're collecting static in `/app/static/` in the gunicorn container. In docker-compose, did you try `- static:/app/static` on the gunicorn side and `- static:/static` on the nginx side?